# next.config.js image remotePatterns config not working on localhost API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi, nextjs-image, next.js14

I am trying to serve content in my Next.js (v14.0.4) app from Strapi CMS. I am able to retrieve content properly but I am having trouble with the media assets. I am capable of retrieving the url of an image asset, and I am trying to configure next.js to prepend the src of the image to point to my CMS using remotePatterns config in my next.config.js file as mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns), but it isn't working. Here is my next.config.js file:

```
// @ts-check

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "localhost", // tried 127.0.0.1 as well
        port: "1337",
        pathname: "/uploads/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

When I run the web app, I console log the url i get from Strapi CMS and can see it is `/uploads/blog_article_1_ea6d1235a5.png`, but the request to retrieve it returns a 404. In dev tools I see the request is being sent to : `http://localhost:3000/uploads/blog_article_1_ea6d1235a5.png`, but it should be `http://localhost:1337/uploads/blog_article_1_ea6d1235a5.png`.

Any idea what could be wrong? Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Your code should work as expect. Can you make a minimal reproduction fot the issue? (New repo that has no code other than the code required to produce the issue)